# Webservice timeout, can't see why

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created a Webservice and a Webclient to go with it. However, I keep hitting a timeout and can't figure out which side it is on. It tells me that it happens on this line:

```
Line 32:         DropDownList1.DataSource = ordersAgent.getCustomers();
```

I looked through the code in the client:

```
 public void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    empName = "Nancy";
    empId = "1";
    Label1.Text = empId.ToString() + ". " + empName.ToString();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = ordersAgent.getCustomers();
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "CompanyName";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "CompanyName";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

    DropDownList2.DataSource = ordersAgent.getSuppliers();
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "CompanyName";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "CompanyName";
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    GetProducts();
}
```

This is the only instance when this function is called from the Webservice. This is the function in the Webservice:

```
 public DataSet getCustomers()
{
    string strProject = "ARTUR\\SQLEXPRESS"; //Enter your SQL server instance name
    string strDatabase = "Northwind"; //Enter your database name
    string strUserID = "Artlemaks"; // Enter your SQL Server User Name
    string strPassword = "rootUser"; // Enter your SQL Server Password
    string strconn = "data source=" + strProject +
      ";Persist Security Info=false;database=" + strDatabase +
      ";user id=" + strUserID + ";password=" +
      strPassword + ";Connection Timeout = 0";

    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strconn))
    {
        //' declare the command that will be used to execute the select statement 
        SqlCommand cmdOrders = new SqlCommand("SELECT CompanyName FROM Customers", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdOrders);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds, "ss");
        con.Close();

        return ds;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I can leave the page alone for a minute and then try to do something that fires an event, and the timeout would come on. If I am quick enough, everything on the page works fine.

Thanks for any kind of advise!

Comment: What is the full stack trace for the timeout? I'm guessing it's sticking on the  `da.Fill`?

Comment: How long does the query take to run if you run it through query window? How many customers are there?

Comment: The full stack trace is too long to paste in the comment so I have placed it here: http://pastebin.com/wQi2iCHL

Comment: @JohnPaul takes about 30 seconds when its run for the first time. Only 91 records

Comment: What are you using for the db? 91 records should return instantly.

Comment: Is customers a table or a view?

Comment: I am using SqlServer running on localhost. Customers is a table.

Comment: Its not like the query is not returning the results though. I can see the list of customers in the dropdown list as soon as the page loads. I can do other things as well (for example, I have a gridview with a textbox that fires an event on TextChanged). Its just that after 1 minute, when I try to do something, it times out.